# Error using DS2 and JSON package

Tags: json, sas, sas-ds2

I'm trying to parse out a JSON file using the JSON package provided for `proc ds2` in SAS9.3 Maintenance 3 as per Chris Hemedinger's blog post here:

http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/09/28/parse-json-from-sas/

Everything seemed to be working fine until I restarted my SAS session and now I keep on getting the message:

```
ERROR: Compilation error.
ERROR: Line 883: Ambiguous method call for method createparser. Multiple method declarations
match the given argument list.
```

Line 883 (in this case) refers to the line that contains the `createParser` call.  Here's some simplified code that can reproduce the error:

```
data have;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

proc ds2;
  data want;

    dcl package json j();   
    dcl int rc;

    method run();
      set have; 
      rc = j.createParser( name );
    end;

  enddata;
run;
quit;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just reran the exact example from the blog post and that is working fine.  So it's definitely something in my code.

Comment: Also tried explicitly declaring the name variable and assigning it a DS2 data type but that didn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right that this is a bug on SAS's part, and I don't see unfortunately a way to confirm to SAS that you're using method 3 and not method 4. Just declaring `name` as character doesn't suffice, for some reason.  Bring up a ticket with SAS for this, I would suggest.

However, I think method 1 is better than method 2 here, given you don't really want to specify the tipping size.  Just move this to INIT (where it belongs anyway) and use `setparserinput`, as is suggested in the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/68052/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1c15oj6g6nak3n12tx7t7j3kj8e.htm):

```
data have;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

proc ds2;
  data want;

    dcl package json j();   
    dcl double rc;
    method init();
      rc = j.createParser();
      j.setParserInput(name);
    end;

    method run();
      set have; 
    end;

  enddata;
run;
quit;
```

Additionally, it looks like the reason the example works is the `character set` argument.  `UTF-8` or `Unicode` will work (the latter won't actually work for other reasons but will not break for *this* reason), while `WLatin1`, `ANSI`, or `ASCII` will not.  Apparently setting it as a UTF-8 character causes SAS to realize it's really character?

```
data have;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

proc ds2;
  data want(overwrite=yes);

    dcl package json j();   
    dcl char(50)  character set utf8 name;
    dcl double rc;
    method init();
      rc = j.createParser( name );
    end;

    method run();
      set have; 
    end;

  enddata;
run;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation (https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/68052/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1w9ms65zrao57n1p1yt4029jcwt.htm) they use method overloading on createParser .  There's 4 methods to choose from and it seems that somehow SAS can't tell which of the 4 I'm trying to call:

Form 1:

```
package.CREATEPARSER ( );
```

Form 2:

```
package.CREATEPARSER (json-text, tipping-size);
```

Form 3:

```
package.CREATEPARSER (json-text);
```

Form 4:

```
package.CREATEPARSER (tipping-size);
```

I found an ugly solution which is simply to call Form 2 in order to make the call unambiguous.  I set the tipping point to 32767 as I'm working with data in SAS tables and none of the results will be longer than that anyway.  Final code:

```
proc ds2;
  data want (overwrite=yes);

    dcl package json j();   
    dcl int rc;

    method init();
      set have; 
      rc = j.createParser( name , 32767 );
    end;

  enddata;
%runquit;
```